# One of my scripts prevents another to execute

Tags: javascript

I have jQuery lightbox working on my site, everything was working fine until I added a js dropdown. Now my drop-down only executes when I remove the lightbox function at the top of the page. Same thing for the lightbox, it only works when I remove the js include for the drop down.

Here's the page - http://norcalwater.blackdogstaging.com/groundwater-management/ 
The dropdown is on the 'Water Managment'. Notice the images in the content that should enlarge within lightbox aren't working.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Move scripts around.
If you'll put them like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/res/js/fancydropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/res/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a.lightbox').lightBox();
});
```

it will be fine.
You're including jQuery library 3 times in `<head>`

jQuery library here

Line 13:`<script type="text/javascript" src="/res/js/jquery.js"></script>`

Line 14:`<script type="text/javascript" src="/res/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>`

jQuery library here

Line 21:`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://norcalwater.blackdogstaging.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>`

jQuery library here (inside this js file there's a jQuery code and sizzle - part of jQuery library)

Line 40:`<script type="text/javascript" src="/res/js/fancydropdown.js"></script>`

As the fancydropdown.js have a jQuery library inside it's now loading jQuery 3 times and then scripts, you should clear it up.

Cheers

G.